# GPUImageOpacityFilter + blend filters

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I have included a list of blend filters in my app. And to adjust the alpha value of blend image, I have used `GPUImageOpacityFilter` with blend filters.

```
self.originalPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0009.JPG"]];

self.opacityFilter = [[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init];
[self.opacityFilter forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(768, 768)];

GPUImageView *filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];
self.view = filterView;

self.picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Monkey.JPG"]];
[self.picture processImage];
[self.picture addTarget:self.opacityFilter];

GPUImageDivideBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageDivideBlendFilter alloc] init];
[blendFilter forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(768, 768)];
[self.opacityFilter addTarget:blendFilter];
[self.originalPicture addTarget:blendFilter];

[blendFilter addTarget:filterView];

[self.picture processImage];
[self.originalPicture processImage];
```

It's work well on following blend filters:
`GPUImageAddBlendFilter
GPUImageDivideBlendFilter
GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter 
GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter
GPUImageDarkenBlendFilter 
GPUImageColorDodgeBlendFilter
GPUImageHardLightBlendFilter
GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter`

And not working on below:
`GPUImageLightenBlendFilter
GPUImageColorBurnBlendFilter
GPUImageLinearBurnBlendFilter
GPUImageScreenBlendFilter
GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter
GPUImageDifferenceBlendFilter 
GPUImageExclusionBlendFilter
GPUImageColorBlendFilter
GPUImageHueBlendFilter
GPUImageSaturationBlendFilter
GPUImageLuminosityBlendFilter`

I know that the concept behind the process(Opacity + blend filter) differ for each filters. Could any one please explain the process?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "not working"? I just checked, and those filters do function with an opacity filter.

Comment: Actually, I can't see any change on image after adjusting opacity value. Then I thought, those filter will works different.

Comment: That's because opacity doesn't factor into their calculations. Look at the fragment shader code in each and you'll see how the alpha channel is processed. I believe all of these comply with the Adobe spec for these blends. If you believe they should treat the alpha channel differently, you're welcome to find the correct reference for the math on this and to fix these fragment shaders.

Comment: No Bard, I didn't mean like that. Any way thanks for your response.:)